How to construct a canonical isomorphism between vector spaces?
Is there any general idea one must know in order to construct a canonical isomorphism between two vector spaces? I do understand that a canonical isomorphism is an isomorphism that is independent of the choice of basis on your vector space, like the isomorphism between $V$ and $V^{**}$.
I am asking this question because I am unable to do this particular exercise in Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler. I have to prove $(V_1 \times V_2)^* \cong V_1^* \times V_2^*$. I could just assume they are finite-dimensional and use the fact that if two vector spaces have the same dimension then they are isomorphic but I don't think that was the intended way to prove this fact.

Maps $f$ from $ V_1\times V_2$ are equivalent to pairs of maps $f_1$ and $f_2$ from $V_1$ and $V_2$ by $f(v_1,v_2)=f_1(v_1)+f_2(v_2)$. Verify this correspondence defines a linear isomorphism.

Note that merely observing that two vector spaces have the same dimension does not suffice to prove they are canonically isomorphic. The proof that two vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic relies heavily on choices of bases!

@ArturoMagidin Oh I see, is there any reason the relation between $f$ and $f_1, f_2$ is a simple sum? I would've thought it had to be a linear combination $f(v_1, v_2) = af_1(v_1) + bf_2(v_2)$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{F}$.
So given the information you've provided, would the canonical isomorphism just be $$A : f_1 + f_2 \mapsto (f_1, f_2) \in V_1^* \times V_2^*$$

@CJDowd Oh yes of course I understand! I was just pondering constructing a regular non-canonical isomorphism instead of a canonical one since the problem just mentions "Isomorphism". But still thank you for reminding me.

The inverse map sends the functional $f$ defined on $V_1\times V_2$ to the pair $(f_1,f_2)$, where $f_1$ is the restriction of $f$ to the vectors of the form $(v_1,0)$, and $f_2$ is the restriction to the vectors $(0,v_2)$. Any choice of nonzero $\alpha$ and $\beta$ would also work, because there is a linear automorphism from $L(V,W)$ to itself obtained by sending $T$ to $\alpha T$ (provided $\alpha\neq 0$) for any vector spaces $V$ and $W$.

To emphasize the point made by @CJDowd, for two general vector spaces $V,W$ there is no such thing as a canonical isomorphism between $V$ and $W$. The concept of "canonical isomorphism" only comes up with particular constructions of vector spaces, usually arising from comparing two particular functors in some kind of special category of vector spaces.

Let $V$ and $W$ be any vector spaces over the same field $F$.  Let $\pi_1\colon V\times W\to V$ be the projection onto the first coordinate, $\pi_1(v,w) = v$; and $\pi_2\colon V\times W\to W$ be the projection onto the second coordinate, $\pi_2(v,w)=w$. Let $\iota_1\colon V\to V\times W$ be the embedding into the first coordinate, $\iota_1(v)=(v,0)$; and $\iota_2\colon W\to V\times W$ be the embedding into the second coordinate, $\iota_2(w) = (0,w)$.
Then $V\times W$ has the following two universal properties (because it is a biproduct for vector spaces):

For any vector space $Z$ over $F$ and any linear transformations $T_V\colon Z\to V$ and $T_W\colon Z\to W$, there exists a unit linear transformation $T\colon Z\to V\times W$ such that $\pi_1\circ T = T_V$ and $\pi_2\circ T=T_W$.

For any vector space $X$ over $F$ and any linear transformation $U_V\colon V\to X$ and $U_W\colon W\to X$, there exists a unique linear transformation $U\colon V\times W\to X$ such that $U_V=U\circ\iota_1$ and $U_W=U\circ\iota_2$.


The maps are: for (1), $T(z) = (T_V(z),T_W(z))$, which can easily be checked to be a linear transformation. For (2), the map $U(v,w) = U_V(v)+U_W(w)$; this follows because $(v,w) = (v,0)+(0,w)$, and the conditions require $U(v,0)=U_V(v)$ and $U(0,w)=U_W(w)$.
That means that there is a natural bijection between $L(V\times W,X)$ and $L(V,X)\times L(W,X)$; and there is a natural bijection between $L(Z,V\times W)$ and $L(Z,V)\times L(Z,W)$. These sets are also vector spaces over $F$ (with the usual addition and scalar multiplication of linear transformations), and it is straightforward to verify that these bijections are in fact linear transformations as well. You should verify this.
Note that we haven't spoken about bases in any way, so all of these are in fact "natural".
Now consider your situation: recall that $V^* = L(V,F)$. So you are being asked to prove that $(V\times W)^*$ is isomorphic to $V^*\times W^*$. But this is precisely the statement that
$$L(V\times W,F) \cong L(V,F)\times L(W,F),$$
which we just said holds for any vector space $X$, and in particular holds for the vector space $F$.
Note, moreover, that this isomorphism does not depend on the spaces being finite dimensional! It holds even if $V$ and $W$ are infinite dimensional. This is a purely categorical isomorphism.

Thank you for your answer! (and for your comments). Did you mean ${\iota}_2 (w) = (0, w)$ in the last line of the first paragraph? Also wouldn't it be $U_V = U \circ {\iota}_1$ and $U_W = U \circ {\iota}_2$? because it wouldn't make sense the other wat around.
Once we have $T(z)$ and $U(v, w)$, I don't understand how there is a bijection between $L(V \times W, X)$ and $L(V, X) \times L(W, X)$

@mastershooter77 Yes on the typos, Fixed. A pair $(U_V,U_W)\in L(V,X)\times L(W,X)$ determines a unique map $U\in L(V\times W,X)$ by item 2. Every $U\in L(V\times W,X)$ determines the pair $(U\circ\iota_1,U\circ \iota_2)\in L(V,X)\times L(W,X)$. The uniqueness clause of 2 ensures these are bijections and inverses of each other.

Woah awesome! Thank you again. "Note, moreover, that this isomorphism does not depend on the spaces being finite-dimensional!" This is actually really crazy! could you expand a bit more on this isomorphism being a categorical isomorphism? I am curious.

@mastershooter77:  That means that it comes from the so-called "categorical properties" of a biproduct (or of a coproduct). That is, it comes purely from condition 2. In any setting in which you have an object that has property $2$, you automatically get the corresponding isomorphism. For example, it holds for the disjoint union of two sets:  if $V$ and $W$ are sets, and $V\amalg W$ is their disjoint union, then the set of maps from $V\amalg W$ to a set $S$ is canonically bijectable with pairs $(f,g)$, $f\colon V\to S$ and $g\colon W\to S$.
